# Rails Best Practice: Split up JS & CSS files by controller or does it not matter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In the first iteration of a Rails app I'm working on, I took fairly great pains to split up the JS and CSS files by controller, making sure that only the necessary JS and CSS are loaded, rather than a single concatenated file bundled together in production using the Sprockets manifest.

I used this technique in my layout:

```
  = stylesheet_link_tag "#{controller_path}_#{controller.action_name}", :media => "all" if MyApp::Application.assets.find_asset("#{controller_path}_#{controller.action_name}.css")
  = javascript_include_tag "#{controller_path}_#{controller.action_name}" if MyApp::Application.assets.find_asset("#{controller_path}_#{controller.action_name}.js")
```

My question is:  Is this necessary, or am I prematurely (or over-) optimizing?  Is this generally considered a good practice, or am I creating unnecessary additional work for not much performance gain at page load?  (I have to manually add each file to the precompile list, which is a huge pain and doesn't feel very DRY).  Should I just stick with default way of doing things, which is splitting up the different files, but keeping that `require tree` in the application.js / css files.

Thoughts, resources, and best practices appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is an antipattern.

It is better to concatenate all the js and css files so that they can be downloaded once and cached by the browser. This is particularly important on mobile devices where they benefit hugely from less numerous but bigger downloads. Leave your files separate but use the asset pipeline (sprockets) to concatenate, minify, and gzip your assets in production.

Comment: Also a great answer - thank you Diego.  I had a hunch this was an antipattern since I don't remember actually reading any major sources that suggested doing it, and now you've confirmed why.  Will be fixed in next release!

Answer (score 1):

The drawback to what you're doing is that you're adding a lot of extra HTTP requests.  You'd have to do the math/benchmark, but I bet you'd be better off simply loading it all up once and letting the client cache it.

+ 2 cents.